# PHP - If variable is within 30 of variable

Tags: php

I have a quick question how would I get for example if Value is more than 50 of PreviousValue I got this code so far:

```
$Value = 1000;
$PreviousValue = 900;
if ($Value > $PreviousValue) {
    echo " has increased in price <br>";
}
```

What would I need to change to get more than 50?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just mean `if ($Value > $PreviousValue + 50) {`?

Comment: Oh  my god. I feel so dumb now how I did not think of that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the **margin** you want to match, in this case `50`, i.e.:

```
$previousValue = 900;
$currentValue = 1000;
$margin = 50;
if ($currentValue > $previousValue + $margin) {
    echo " has increased in price <br>";
}
```